# In pandas, how to update a dataframe from another, which is smaller and with the same characteristics?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In python 3 and pandas I have two dataframes with the same columns

```
df_one.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
uf                      8576 non-null object
cargo                   8576 non-null object
sequencial              8576 non-null int64
numero_urna             8576 non-null object
nome_completo           8576 non-null object
nome_urna               8576 non-null object
cpf                     8576 non-null object
e_mail                  8576 non-null object
situacao_candidatura    8576 non-null object


df_two.info()
uf                      102 non-null object
cargo                   102 non-null object
sequencial              102 non-null int64
numero_urna             102 non-null object
nome_completo           102 non-null object
nome_urna               102 non-null object
cpf                     102 non-null object
e_mail                  102 non-null object
situacao_candidatura    102 non-null object
```

The dataframe df_one has historical information about people. Some people's information changes over time. Column "cpf" is an identification code

The dataframe df_two is smaller. It is a file sent only with changes of people information. Also has the column "cpf"

I need to update the "df_one" information with the "df_two" received

That is, all rows that have the same "cpf" in both dataframes need to be updated - the "df_one" needs to have the content of "df_two". But other lines must remain the same

Please, does anyone know how I can do this?

Example of the first lines of df_one:

```
{'uf': {0: 'AC', 1: 'AC', 2: 'AC', 3: 'AC', 4: 'AC'},
 'cargo': {0: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL',
  1: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL',
  2: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL',
  3: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL',
  4: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL'},
 'sequencial': {0: 10000600207,
  1: 10000602510,
  2: 10000602299,
  3: 10000608399,
  4: 10000600222},
 'numero_urna': {0: '1712', 1: '2222', 2: '1277', 3: '1331', 4: '1700'},
 'nome_completo': {0: 'DANIELA PAIVA DE OLIVEIRA',
  1: 'ANTÔNIA LUCILÉIA CRUZ RAMOS CÂMARA',
  2: 'CLEIDE MARIA FERREIRA DE ARAUJO',
  3: 'LEONARDO CUNHA DE BRITO',
  4: 'MICHELA BATISTA LACERDA'},
 'nome_urna': {0: 'DANIELA PAIVA',
  1: 'ANTÔNIA LÚCIA',
  2: 'CLEIDE ARAÚJO DA SAÚDE',
  3: 'LEO DE BRITO',
  4: 'MICHELA LACERDA'},
 'cpf': {0: '52614174220',
  1: '50791524272',
  2: '30864372272',
  3: '63182246291',
  4: '51378353234'},
 'e_mail': {0: 'PSL17.AC@GMAIL.COM',
  1: 'ANTONIALUCIACAMARAPR22@GMAIL.COM',
  2: 'PDTACRE12@GMAIL.COM',
  3: 'LEODEBRITOACRE@GMAIL.COM',
  4: 'PSL17.AC@GMAIL.COM'},
 'situacao_candidatura': {0: 'AGUARDANDO JULGAMENTO',
  1: 'AGUARDANDO JULGAMENTO',
  2: 'AGUARDANDO JULGAMENTO',
  3: 'AGUARDANDO JULGAMENTO',
  4: 'AGUARDANDO JULGAMENTO'}}
```

Example of the first lines of df_two:

```
{'uf': {0: 'AC', 1: 'AC', 2: 'AC', 3: 'AC', 4: 'AC'},
 'cargo': {0: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL',
  1: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL',
  2: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL',
  3: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL',
  4: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL'},
 'sequencial': {0: 10000600207,
  1: 10000602510,
  2: 10000602299,
  3: 10000608399,
  4: 10000600222},
 'numero_urna': {0: '1712', 1: '2222', 2: '1277', 3: '1331', 4: '1700'},
 'nome_completo': {0: 'DANIELA PAIVA DE OLIVEIRA',
  1: 'ANTÔNIA LUCILÉIA CRUZ RAMOS CÂMARA',
  2: 'CLEIDE MARIA FERREIRA DE ARAUJO',
  3: 'LEONARDO CUNHA DE BRITO',
  4: 'MICHELA BATISTA LACERDA'},
 'nome_urna': {0: 'DANIELA PAIVA',
  1: 'ANTÔNIA LÚCIA',
  2: 'CLEIDE ARAÚJO DA SAÚDE',
  3: 'LEO DE BRITO',
  4: 'MICHELA LACERDA'},
 'cpf': {0: '52614174220',
  1: '50791524272',
  2: '30864372272',
  3: '63182246291',
  4: '51378353234'},
 'e_mail': {0: 'PSL17.AC@GMAIL.COM',
  1: 'ANTONIALUCIACAMARAPR22@GMAIL.COM',
  2: 'PDTACRE12@GMAIL.COM',
  3: 'LEODEBRITOACRE@GMAIL.COM',
  4: 'PSL17.AC@hotmail.COM'},
 'situacao_candidatura': {0: 'AGUARDANDO JULGAMENTO',
  1: 'AGUARDANDO JULGAMENTO',
  2: 'RENUNCIA',
  3: 'AGUARDANDO JULGAMENTO',
  4: 'CANCELADO'}}
```

-/-

I followed these steps:

1 - I loaded the historical dataframe df_one, of 8,576 lines

2 - I loaded the dataframe sent of update, of yesterday 27, with 25 lines of update, df_two

3 - df_one.update (df_two)

4 - I saved df_one as a file - df_currentversion.csv - I checked and the 25 new lines were there

5 - I uploaded the updated df_currentversion dataframe of 8,576 lines

6 - I loaded the new dataframe sent of update, of today 28, with 86 lines of update, df_two

7 - df_currentversion.update (df_two)

8 - The 86 lines have been updated, but the previous 25 that have been updated have returned to the way they were in step 1

Comment: Does `df_three = pd.concat([df_two, df_one]).drop_duplicates(subset=['cpf'])` do what you're after? That's a rather naive operation though so if you're looking to merge columns from one into two where they're blank or something that's a different thing...

Comment: Thank you. I put up what I did with the "update". Also tried its way (concat) but the result generates a smaller dataframe of 8,545

Comment: Did you check after step 5 that your alterations from step 3 were present?

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves when you say smaller dataframe - is that using the concat approach? Are you sure if so, it's not the different between len(df1) + len(df2) - duplicated entries on cpf?